# WebdriverIo is not able to initialize wdio-rerun-service : Getting below error

Tags: webdriver-io

[0-13] 2022-05-25T04:33:05.332Z DEBUG @wdio/utils:initialiseServices: initialise service "selenium-standalone" as NPM package
[0-13] 2022-05-25T04:33:05.350Z DEBUG @wdio/utils:initialiseServices: initialise service "RerunService" as NPM package
[0-13] 2022-05-25T04:33:05.351Z ERROR @wdio/utils:initialiseServices: **Error: Couldn't find plugin "RerunService" service, neither as wdio scoped package "@wdio/rerunservice-service" nor as community package "wdio-rerunservice-service". Please make sure you have it installed!**
at Object.initialisePlugin [as default] (/Users/*****/dotor/dot-or-automation/node_modules/@wdio/runner/node_modules/@wdio/utils/build/initialisePlugin.js:26:11)
at initialiseServices (/Users/****/dotor/dot-or-automation/node_modules/@wdio/runner/node_modules/@wdio/utils/build/initialiseServices.js:24:51)
at Object.initialiseWorkerService (/Users/*****/dotor/dot-or-automation/node_modules/@wdio/runner/node_modules/@wdio/utils/build/initialiseServices.js:67:26)
at Runner.run (/Users/*******/dotor/dot-or-automation/node_modules/@wdio/runner/build/index.js:43:17)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
[0-13] Capabilities: {"maxInstances":2,"browserName":"chrome","acceptInsecureCerts":true,"goog:chromeOptions":{}}
[0-13] 2022-05-25T04:33:05.437Z DEBUG @wdio/sync: Finished to run "beforeSession" hook in 0ms
2022-05-25T04:33:05.800Z DEBUG @wdio/local-runner: Runner 0-13 finished with exit code 0
2022-05-25T04:33:05.800Z INFO @wdio/cli: [0-13] SKIPPED in chrome - /automation/features/ui/Others/setting-wheel.feature
2022-05-25T04:33:05.800Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onWorkerEnd hook

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you already found your answer for this but if you haven't. The webdriverio doc explains it well.

```
// wdio.conf.js
const RerunService = require('wdio-rerun-service');
export.config = {
    // ...
    services: [RerunService, {
        // ...
    }]
};
```

This service is slightly configured differently compared to the other ones.
Note that we are importing the service and using it in the config object. Other services are usually called directly after installation, and the name of the service is usually a string example:

```
export.config = {
    // ...
    services: ["selenium-standalone", {
        // ...
    }]
};
```